# XML and linq question to find child of father

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**hmm mabye i asked litle strange. How can i get all child of type "Title".

There is many of children of type "Title"

Like:

```
- <BiblioDiv>
  <Title>**</Title> 

- <BiblioDiv>
  <BiblioAsk>
  <Title>***</Title> 

- <BiblioEntry>
  <BiblioDiv>
  <Title>**</Title>
```

I just need to get all "Title". Can i get this with linq and without all loops?
I try with XElement becouse is then easy work with.

With XElement i can use:

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.LoadXml(xml);

 XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Title");
```

How can i use this with XElement

Comment: You can use xpath to locate the element. A sample of the XML perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it always exists:

```
root.Element("BiblioDiv").Element("Title")
```

Otherwise:

```
root.XPathSelectElement("BiblioDiv/Title")
```

avoids null reference exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean:

```
var child = element.Element("Title");
```

or:

```
var child = elements.Elements("BiblioDiv").First().Element("Title");
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You can use element.Elements(XName.Get("Title")) to access only child elemnts with the specified name.

Comment: `element.Elements("Title")` is probably easier in this scenario